# Firebase multi-path update fails due to slash char

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm following this Firebase tutorial(multi-path update):
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-update

But when I try to run:

```
firebaseRef.update({
   'alanisawesome/nickname': 'Alan The Machine',
  'gracehop/nickname': 'Amazing Grace'
});
```

I get:

```
Error: Firebase.update failed:
First argument  contains an invalid key (alanisawesome/nickname) .
Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

I need the "/" character for specifying the path.
What could be wrong with my implementation?

Thanks

Comment: See [Exception when ordering query by nested data with Firebase Android API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996382/exception-when-ordering-query-by-nested-data-with-firebase-android-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated firebase from version 2.2.9 to the latest version (2.3.2) and this problem doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure why this should matter, but it seems (based on the example you linked) like you may be using the wrong type of quotes. Try replacing your code with this, using double quotes instead of single:

```
firebaseRef.update({
   "alanisawesome/nickname": "Alan The Machine",
  "gracehop/nickname": "Amazing Grace"
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a multi-path update. according to the tutorial you need the slash char, in order to specify the path in the database. Omitting the slash char will result in update of a wrong "cell"

Answer (score 0):

Deep path support was added in Firebase javascript version 2.3.0, which you can see in the [changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html).  Thus, you must be using a version of Firebase which supports it in order for the functionality to be available.

Use a version equal to or later than 2.3.0.

Thanks to [Androidparanoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042974/androidparanoid)'s answer for helping me figure this out, but I feel that a more concise explanation would be helpful to posterity.